# Find the Average of percentage complete from php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this structure in table named customer_type_total_avg

```
USEDID       CID            TYPE           PERCENTAGECOMPLETED
-------      ----           ----           ------------------
1            6              external       12
1            6              external       50
1            6              internal       50
1            6              external       84
1            6              internal       100
1            6              external       100

function getCustomerprogress($where) {
    $progress = 0;
    $cid = $where["cid"];
    $userid = $where["userid"];
    $sql = "SELECT 
    TRUNCATE(avg(t.percentage),1) as avg_percentage
    FROM
    (SELECT 
           percentagecompleted as 'percentage'
    FROM
        customer_type_total_avg
    WHERE
        userid = $userid and cid = $cid) AS t";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $progress = $row["avg_percentage"];
        }
    }
    return $progress;
}
```

I need a SELECT query to find the total average of the rows WHERE USERID and CID are matching

NOTE : we should include this below condition also in SELECT query to get average

1. When the "TYPE" is 'external' it should consider whatever the value in column "percentagecompleted"
2. When the "TYPE" is 'internal' and percentagecompleted = '50',Then it should replace the value of percentagecompleted = '0' and it should consider the row for finding the average

Example: From the above table, we have matching six rows and it will consider the external type percentagecompleted value for average calculation and in third row the percentagecompleted is '50' for internal, what i need is to replace the value to '0' and find the average for total number of rows

```
USEDID       CID            TYPE           PERCENTAGECOMPLETED
-------      ----           ----           ------------------
1            6              external       12
1            6              external       50
1            6              internal       0
1            6              external       84
1            6              internal       100
1            6              external       100
```

Comment: Where is your code that you have tried?

Comment: Post your code first

Comment: i have posted @Santhosh

Comment: @ShashankShah are you understand what i need!

Comment: according to your requirement, I don't think you do need to use AVG() at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE`.

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN TYPE='internal' and PERCENTAGECOMPLETED=50 
                THEN 0 
                ELSE PERCENTAGECOMPLETED END) AS AVG
FROM CUSTOMER_TYPE_TOTAL_AVG
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f6111d7cd64117d62c7909e522d5553)

Comment: Welcome ! I would appreciate if you can mark this answer as right by clicking the tick option If this helped to solve your problem. [HOW TO ACCEPT AN ANSWER](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)  @Arun

Comment: Yes.. @Arun Palanisamy